# I need to change my page numbers for my thesis but don't know how

Tags: page-numbering, thesis

To finally submit my thesis my advisor keeps saying "Bottom page numbers must be set at the 1” margin from the bottom" I am using the following packages and page numbering, but I don't know how to fix this specific issue. someone please help.

```
\documentclass[masters, final]
\usepackage{docmute}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix} 
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\ifxetex
   \usepackage{fontspec}
   \setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\fi
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please provide the mandatory argument of `\documentclass`.

Comment: You can use the geometry package to set margins, but the footer (page number) is placed \footsep below the top of the bottom margin, so you want the bottom margin - footsep to equal 1in.

Comment: I'm afraid that an instruction such as "Bottom page numbers must be set at the 1” margin from the bottom" is highly incomplete. What about other page parameters, such as the width and height of the text block? And, do *all* page numbers have to be set at the bottom center, or just the ones on the first pages of chapters? Please advise.